# Binary manipulation

Tags: c#, binary

I am trying to code up the SHA-256 algorithm as shown by https://blog.boot.dev/cryptography/how-sha-2-works-step-by-step-sha-256/. From what I can tell, my code is perfect up until this algorithm:

```
for (int i = 16; i < 64; i++)
{
    s0 = s1 = "";

    right7 = rotate(w[i - 15], 7);
    right18 = rotate(w[i - 15], 18);
    right3 = "000" + w[i - 15].Remove(29);
    s0 = xor(xor(right7, right18), right3);

    right17 = rotate(w[i - 2], 17);
    right19 = rotate(w[i - 2], 19);
    right10 = "0000000000" + w[i - 2].Remove(22);

    s1 = xor(xor(right17, right19), right10);
    w[i] = add(add(add(s0, s1), w[i - 16]), w[i-7]);
}
```

Here are the sub-routines for add, rotate and xor:

```
static string rotate(string input, int amount)
{
    return input.Substring(32-amount) + input.Remove(32-amount);
}

static string add(string input1, string input2)
{
    string output = "";
    Int64 one = Convert.ToInt64(input1, 2);
    Int64 two = Convert.ToInt64(input2, 2);
    Int64 total = one + two;
    if (total > (Math.Pow(2, 32)))
    {
        total -= Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(2, 32));
    } 
    output = Convert.ToString(total, 2);
    if (output.Length < 32)
    {
        output = new string('0', 32 - output.Length) + output;
    }
    return output;
}

static string xor(string input1, string input2)
{
    int total;
    string output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        total = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(input1[i])) + Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(input2[i]));
        
        if (total == 1)
        {
            output += '1';
        }
        else
        {
            output += '0';
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

The first iteration of I works, but then the second one doesn't by a couple of binary digits, and past the number 22, it's completely wrong. Any ideas or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Padding adds random bytes at end of data to make it harder for hackers to see the real data (key).  If you are having issues look at the padding in the link at PSEUDO Code.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, why not use the existing cryptgraphy libraries in C#?